# Select Field not populating via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to achieve this feature. That when users who want to post ads selects a category then an `.change()` JQUERY method tiggers an AJAX request which will request for sub categories from the SUB-CATEGORIES Table that belong to the selected CATEGORY and append the results on the the next SELECT FIELD. But so far its not getting the Results.

This are my code snippets.

**subcat.php**

```
<?php

include 'includes/config.php';

if (isset($_POST['category'])) {

    $cat = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['category']);
    //select category id from categories table where Title = $cat
    $catIdSel = "SELECT cat_id FROM categories WHERE catTitle = '$cat'";
    $catIdSelKwary = mysqli_query($link, $catIdSel);
    $catIdSelCount = mysqli_nums_row($catIdSelKwary);
    if ($catIdSelCount == 1) {
        $catIdRow = mysqli_fetch_array($catIdSelKwary);

        $cat_id = $catIdRow['cat_id'];
    }

    //select from sub-categories table all the sub-categories that have the same cat_id with the returned cat_id from the dategories table

        $subCatSel = "SELECT Title FROM sub_categories WHERE cat_id = '$cat_id'";
        $subCatSelKwary = mysqli_query($link, $subCatSel);
        $subCatSelCount = mysqli_nums_row($subCatSelKwary);
        if ($catIdSelCount > 0) {

            while ($subCatRow = mysqli_fetch_array($subCatSelKwary)) {

                echo '<option value="'.$subCatRow['Title'].'">' .$subCatRow['Title']. '</option>';
            }
        }else{
            echo "No Sub Category for this Category yet";
        }
}
```

**postad.php** - where my Jquery is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#category').change(function () {
            //display loading option
            $('#sub-category').html('<option value="">Fetching Sub Categories...</option>');
            //collect select value
            var category = $('#category').val();

            $.ajax({
                URL: 'sel_subcat.php?cat' + category,
                method: 'POST',
                data: category,
                success: function (data) {
                    //append the data to the select field
                    $('#sub-category').html(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log(xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Below is the image of the page/form

[image: image of the form, showing the two select boxes]

[image: this is the errors i get from the console]

Comment: Line `URL: 'sel_subcat.php?cat'+category` should be `URL: 'sel_subcat.php?cat='+category`. You missed an equals sign (`=`).

Comment: I think you `data` field in your ajax request should be like this `data : {
    'category': category 
  },`

Comment: Ok @psinaught. let me try that

Comment: I don't think the part after `sel_subcat.php` is necessary as you declare the method is `POST` and you check for `isset $_POST['category']`

Comment: I do not know if this is relevant buy you have `if (isset($_POST['category']))` and then  `$_GET['category']` I guess here you require to be `$_POST['category']`

Comment: replace `$_POST` to `$_GET`

Comment: Still not working ...

Comment: Do you have a message in the console?

Comment: You are sending with POST your url could be `url: 'sel_subcat.php` and `sel_subcat.php` should be a path for example `url: '/sel_sub_cat.php'`

Answer (score 0):

This can help you

```
           var category = $('#category').val();

            $.ajax({
                URL: 'sel_subcat.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {category:category},
                success:function(data){
                    //append the data to the select field
                    $('#sub-category').html(data);
                },
                error:function () {
                    console.log(xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
                }
            });
```

And Use $_POST['category'] To Recieve the Data.